# Bind data into my form in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

I have a form which I use in my viewscript. My viewscript looks as follows:

```
<?php
$this->titel = "Arbeitskalender Termine";
$this->headTitle($this->titel);
foreach($this->aktermine as $termin) :
    $this->nr=$this->escape($termin->nr);
    $this->kopfnr=$this->escape($termin->kopfnr);
    $this->datum=$this->escape($termin->datum);
    $this->zeit=$this->escape($termin->zeit);
    $this->thema=$this->escape($termin->thema);
    echo $this->form ;
endforeach;
?>
```

I get my form (it is a table) I get the same repeats of the form like records in my table. But I don´t see any record in the form fields. What´s wrong? How can I get the values of my dataset objects in each field?
If I use a viewscript in html it works fine.

Comment: If I correctly understood your question, you're trying to populate your form, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the the form’s `bind()` method to attach your model to the form. The value for each field will be extracted from the model and displayed in the form.

> This is used in two ways:
>
> - When displaying the form, the initial values for each element are
>     extracted from the model.
> - After successful validation in `isValid()`, the data from the form is put back into the model.

To use this method you need to implement `getArrayCopy()` and `exchangeArray()` in your model `Aktermine`.

So in your action you'll have something like this:

```
$form = new YourForm();
$form->bind($aktermine);
```

Please see the example of [Editing an Album](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/user-guide/forms-and-actions.html#editing-an-album), in the documentation.

Read also [Binding Objects to Forms](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/data-binding.html#binding-objects-to-forms)

If you are using doctrine, just add `getArrayCopy()` into your entity like this:

```
public function getArrayCopy(){
  return get_object_vars($this);
}
```

And then within your controller action :

```
$form->bind($yourEntity);
```

Comment: OK thanks, I will try it, and eventually come back later with another question.